# Nginx Location Block for Dynamic Url Segment

Tags: php, nginx

My PHP app automatically detects that a request routes to the admin area via the keyword manage in the url ie:

http://example.com/manage

This directory doesn't actually exist.

The request should route to the index.php file which is does on the initial request to manage/ but any links produce a "No input file specified." error in nginx.

I need a location block that will work on a non-existent url segment.

I tried re-writing it to the main index file like so:

```
location /manage {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @back;
}

location @back {
    rewrite ^/manage/(.*)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
}
```

which works fine for Apache but in Nginx this produces a 500 error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

Full config requested in comments:

```
upstream myapp {
    server unix:/srv/users/serverpilot/run/myapp.php-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.domain.com;

    root /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/myapp/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log /srv/users/serverpilot/log/myapp/myapp_nginx.access.log;
    error_log  /srv/users/serverpilot/log/myapp/myapp_nginx.error.log;

    location /asset {
        rewrite ^/asset/(.*)$ /public/asset/$1 break;
    }

    location /image {
        rewrite ^/image/(.*)$ /public/image/$1 break;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @front;
    }

    location @front {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass myapp;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Error log requested.

```
15/05/14 10:42:04 [error] 32704#0: 
*5 FastCGI sent in stderr: 
"Unable to open primary script: /srv/users/username/apps/myapp/public/manage/index.php (No such file or directory)" 
while reading response header from upstream, client: 129.349.569.789, 
server: myapp.example.com, 
request: "GET /manage/index.php?route=common/forgotten HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9002", 
host: "myapp.example.com", 
referrer: "http://myapp.example.com/manage"
```

**UPDATE:**

Requested `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^asset/(.*)$ public/asset/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^image/(.*)$ public/image/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|txt|html|woff|ttf|eot|svg|css|js)
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: And where these links leads to?

Comment: BTW, if you're sure that `manage` directory not exist you could skip `try_files` and put rewrite right in first location

Comment: All urls with the keyword `manage` route to the admin controllers through index.php.  And yes I'm sure the directory doesn't exist.

Comment: Show full nginx config. Does any other php works?

Comment: Config added to question. Yes all php works for front of application.

Comment: «but any links produce a "No input file specified."» Do these links in form of `/manage/something.php`?

Comment: Yes. manage/index.php?route=common/home&token=123456etc and all similar.

Comment: Is nginx leaving any hints in myapp_nginx.error.log?

Comment: Basically just a file not found error. I'll post it in the question.

Comment: Updated answer to match Apache Rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be right under my nose the whole time.

```
upstream myapp {
    server localhost:9002;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.example.com;

    root /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/myapp/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    access_log /srv/users/serverpilot/log/myapp/myapp_nginx.access.log;
    error_log  /srv/users/serverpilot/log/myapp/myapp_nginx.error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @front;
    }

    location ~ ^/manage {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass myapp;
    }

    location @front {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
    }
}
```

Thanks to @Dayo for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

From the error log and configuration you posted, the request for `/manage/index.php?route=common/forgotten` will match both the `/` and `php` location blocks.

Given how the [Nginx Location Matching Order](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) is set out, the PHP location block will always take precedence and so the request is passed to FastCGI to process and as `site.com/manage/index.php` does not exist, you get an error. That is, the `try_files` in `/` and the rewrite in `@front`never get into the picture at all.

What you need to do is to add a location block that has a higher position in the location matching order than the PHP location block to handle such requests.

```
upstream myapp {
    server unix:/srv/users/serverpilot/run/myapp.php-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    root /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/myapp/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log /srv/users/serverpilot/log/myapp/myapp_nginx.access.log;
    error_log  /srv/users/serverpilot/log/myapp/myapp_nginx.error.log;

    location /asset {
        rewrite ^/asset/(.*)$ /public/asset/$1 break;
    }

    location /image {
        rewrite ^/image/(.*)$ /public/image/$1 break;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @front;
    }

    location ~ ^/manage {
        rewrite ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?_route_=$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass myapp;
    }

    location @front {
        rewrite ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?_route_=$1;
    }
}
```

With this arrangement, the request will match the `/`, `/Manage` and `php` location blocks. `/Manage` and `php` being regex type blocks, will take precedence and among the two, `/Manage`, because it appears first, will take precedence and redirect accordingly.

For the redirection, the request will match the `/`, and `php` location blocks. `php` will take precedence and as `site.com/index.php` does exist, process accordingly.

PS. I notice you have `_route_` in your config and `route` in the log. Take it that is just for testing.

## **** ALTERNATIVE CONFIG ****

```
upstream myapp {
    server unix:/srv/users/serverpilot/run/myapp.php-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    root /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/myapp/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log /srv/users/serverpilot/log/myapp/myapp_nginx.access.log;
    error_log  /srv/users/serverpilot/log/myapp/myapp_nginx.error.log;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass myapp;
    }

    location ~ ^/asset/(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^ public/asset/$1;
    }

    location ~ ^/image/(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^ public/image/$1;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @front;
    }

    location @front {
        rewrite ^/([^?]*)$ /index.php?_route_=$1;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Nope this doesn't work. With both `manage` rewrites enabled, and with only the second one enabled, the url just loads up the normal index page.  If I comment out the second `manage` rewrite I get a 404.

Comment: The entire url for the admin area needs to remain intact. The admin area doesn't use any url rewriting at all other than the `manage` segment. That segment tells the application to load the admin module. If that segment isn't present in the url, the application knows to load the front module.

Comment: @VinceK That is actually positive as it means the `manage` block is handling the requests now and the rewrite just needs to be right. I had thought you wanted to change incoming requests of the form, `site.com/manage/ABC/XYZ`to `site.com/index.php?_route_=ABC/XYZ` which seems not to be the case. So, can you give a sample incoming request/link and what the application is expecting? With this info, it will be trivial to tweak the rewrite rule accordingly.

Comment: Absolutely. Links to the admin should be left as is `example.com/manage/index.php?route=xxx/xxx&token=1234&product_id=5678` and so on. Thanks BTW for your help.

Comment: Just for clarification, the `manage` segment is selectable by the end user. It could be set to `steve` or `aardvarks`, whatever the user of the app wants in order to keep their admin area a secret.

Comment: Sorry, but no webserver can process that request without a rewrite if there isn't a physical `manage` folder with an index.php file sitting in there. You say it works with Apache, can you paste the rewrite rule Apache uses to handle the request? There must be one as this is not an Nginx specific requirement. the only other alternative is that you are missing something major out of, or adding something major into,  the example url you have given.

Comment: I'll add it to the question.

Comment: In response to your comment, that's the same thought I had, so I tried sending with `$is_args$args` but it still doesn't work. rewrite to `/$uri` is the only thing that makes sense at this point.

Comment: Why not just try changing the first rewrite in my answer to be equivalent to  the Apache one? That is,  `rewrite ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1`

Comment: I did. From my previous comment: `If I comment out the second manage rewrite I get a 404.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77988/discussion-between-dayo-and-vince-kronlein).